# Como puedo imprimir cada uno de los documentos que me trae una consulta menos los que acaben en -1 C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema para imprimir todos los documentos que traigo al GRID cuando terminan en -1 ejemplo (cobro789-1) no debe imprimir ese y saltar al que sigue.

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        r = new imprimirmanifiesto();
        int pos = 0;
        //bool a = true;
        for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            r.imprimir(dataGridView1.Rows[pos].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pero nunca incrementas pos. y si pruebas con un foreach

Comment: es que imprimo muchos documentos y no se en que momento puede no exixtir uno

Comment: Cambia esta linea a ver que ocurre:    r.imprimir(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString());

Comment: Parece claramente un error tipografico como marca @MichaelOspina

Comment: cual seria el error? funciona bien hasta que trata de imprimir un documento que no existe

Comment: veo ese codigo desde muchos lados y me parece que esta mal, tienes un error garrafal en "row" y "pos" 

tu codigo le esta diciendo al programa que siempre imprima el primer documento

Comment: Entiendo, como podria hacer que pase por todos los datos que me trae la consulta?

Comment: podria ser asi?  

    foreach (int element in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                r.imprimir(dataGridView1.Rows[pos].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    r = new imprimirmanifiesto();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString())
            && !row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("-1"))
            r.imprimir(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias lo voy a probar

Comment: Me equivoque un poco ya lo corregí amigo, saludos espero te sirva.

Comment: No me imprime, debo aclarar que en los documentos que me trae ejemplo (cobro789-1) cualquier documento que llegue con (-1) no debe ser imprimido y debe saltar al suiguiente

Comment: cambia la condicional por esta:

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()) && !row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("-1"))

Comment: Excelente victor ya me discrimina los -1 e imprime los demas, muy amable

Comment: Que bueno saludos amigo, siempre a la orden.